# How to find disk path of a process

Tags: process

If a process is running how can I find its disk path using command on terminal ? In my case a process synergy is running and I want to locate it on disk

```
ps -ef
```

shows the path of other processes but not this one.

Comment: can you clarify what exactly you need ? you want the location of the executable file ?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the PID of the process, you can examine the contents of its `/proc` entry, in particular, the `exe` file:

```
$ ls -l /proc/$$/exe   
lrwxrwxrwx 1 muru muru 0 Apr 17 19:41 /proc/13339/exe -> /usr/bin/zsh
$ sudo ls -l /proc/1/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 17 17:40 /proc/1/exe -> /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
```

IIRC what `ps -ef` reports are the arguments of the process (starting from `argv[0]`, which is the command called as is), but a process is free to rewrite its arguments. Hence `ps -ef` may not be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You have written:

> If a process is running how can I find its disk path using command on
>   terminal ? In my case a process synergy is running and I want to
>   locate it on disk

Open a terminal and run the following commands, depending on how you want to proceed. I use *synergy* because you mentioned it:

- If you really want to use *ps*, then you can use this command.

  ```
  ps -o command= -p "$(ps -C synergy -o pid=)" | xargs which
  ```
- If you want to know just where the executable is located, then use this command

  ```
  which synergy
  ```